# Problems with "running" functionality

Tags: vb.net

I am a new programmer learning Visual Basic.
Right now, I'm working on a project about a softball scoreboard. I have been working on this project for a bit, and I am confused on 1 thing.

The thing I am confused on is that I put in a messagebox that said invalid input for negative numbers, but it does not delete it from lstScores and even though the message box appears it still counts as a inning input.

```
If runs < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show(VALID_MESSAGE)
```

This is the code:

```
Public Class frmSoftballScoreboard
    Const VALID_MESSAGE As String = "Enter valid runs value"
    Const ONLY_MESSAGE As String = "Only seven innings are allowed"
    'Declaring array
    Dim scores(6) As Double
    'declaring variables
    Dim runs As String
    Dim runningScore As Integer = 0
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim out As Double

    'page load event
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lstScores.Items.Add("Runs : Running Score")
    End Sub
    'Enter score button
    Private Sub btnScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnScore.Click

        If i < scores.Length Then
            'display inputbox to the user
            runs = InputBox("Enter score for " & (i + 1) & " innings", "Score")
            'if runs is entered
            If runs <> "" Then
                'parse the value of runs
                If (Double.TryParse(runs, out)) Then
                    'parse the runs and add it to the array scores()
                    scores(i) = Double.Parse(runs)
                    runningScore += scores(i)
                    'add the rainfall value to the listbox along with month name
                    lstScores.Items.Add(scores(i) & " :" & runningScore)
                    'increment the value of i
                    i = i + 1
                Else
                    'display error message
                    MessageBox.Show(VALID_MESSAGE)
                    lblTotal.Text = ""
                End If
            Else
                'if runs is empty then display error message
                MessageBox.Show("Enter runs for " & i & "innings")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(ONLY_MESSAGE)
        End If
        If runs < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show(VALID_MESSAGE)
        End If
        'calculate total runs And display on the lable
        If scores(6) = 7 Then
            lblTotal.Text = String.Format("final score is {0}", scores.Sum())
        End If
    End Sub
    'Clear Menu click
    Private Sub ClearToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuClear.Click
        lstScores.Items.Clear()
        lblTotal.Text = ""
        'reset i to 0
        i = 0
    End Sub
    'Exit Menu click
    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuExit.Click
        'close application
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I would really appreciate it if you could help. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to do something repeatedly then you need a loop.  If you don't know how loops work, you should do some research on that subject. If you do know how they work, you need to decide what type of loop is most appropriate in this scenario.

Comment: Each question you post here needs to be specific.  You have asked about two unrelated topics here.  Please edit your question and remove everything related to the second topic, then post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub btnScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnScore.Click
    If i < scores.Length Then
        'display inputbox to the user
        runs = InputBox("Enter score for " & (i + 1) & " innings", "Score")
        'if runs is entered
        If runs < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show(VALID_MESSAGE)
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf runs <> "" Then
            'parse the value of runs
            If (Double.TryParse(runs, out)) Then
                'parse the runs and add it to the array scores()
                scores(i) = Double.Parse(runs)
                runningScore += scores(i)
                'add the rainfall value to the listbox along with month name
                lstScores.Items.Add(scores(i) & " :" & runningScore)
                'increment the value of i
                i = i + 1
            Else
                'display error message
                MessageBox.Show(VALID_MESSAGE)
                lblTotal.Text = ""
            End If
        Else
            'if runs is empty then display error message
            MessageBox.Show("Enter runs for " & i & "innings")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(ONLY_MESSAGE)
    End If
    If runs < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show(VALID_MESSAGE)
    End If
    'calculate total runs And display on the lable
    If scores(6) = 7 Then
        lblTotal.Text = String.Format("final score is {0}", scores.Sum())
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the reason why if you input invalid data it will add into `lstScores`, because your `If statement..` is in bottom of your code, although is not recommend where you put the `If else statement..`. Remember reading of the code is start in top to bottom.

Your first `If statement` is like this. `If runs <> "" then ....`, of course if you type the `-1` value in the `Input Text` the Boolean will result to true, `If -1 <> "" = true`, then it will proceed to the statement which is

```
 If (Double.TryParse(runs, out)) Then
    'parse the runs and add it to the array scores()
     scores(i) = Double.Parse(runs)
     runningScore += scores(i)
     'add the rainfall value to the listbox along with month name
     lstScores.Items.Add(scores(i) & " :" & runningScore)
     'increment the value of i
     i = i + 1
```

This is the line of code even the value is invalid or not it still adding value in the `lstScores`, `lstScores.Items.Add(scores(i) & " :" & runningScore)`

Now after that statement you will receive a message which is :

> Enter valid runs value

```
 If runs < 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show(VALID_MESSAGE)
 End If
```

That code is the reason why you receiving the message. If you input `-1` of course the result of boolean is true, why? `-1 is lessthan to 0` which is true.

The thing i do is, I've insert `If statement..` above, which is `If runs < 0 then ....` and also `Exit Sub` to instantly end the statement. If you input `-1` to `Input Text` the result is something like this, if `runs(-1)` lessthan to `0` the Boolean result is true then it will proceed to statement which is the Message and `Exit Sub`.

Try my code above, and also use Breakpoints.. Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it. It makes a lot of sense. This helps a lot.